# Is Koszulity equivalent to the Lusztig character formula holding?

Tags: algebraic-groups, kazhdan-lusztig, koszul-algebras

Let $\pi$ denote a saturated set of weights. Let $S_q(\pi)$ denote the associated generalised $q$-Schur algebra.  I was wondering if the following claim is true:

Claim: The algebra $S_q(\pi)$ is Koszul if and only if the decomposition numbers of $S_q(\pi)$ are given by the associated Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials.

In characteristic zero and `sufficiently large primes' I believe this is true by work of Andersen-Jantzen-Soergel and Riche.  But is it true or believed to be true over fields of arbitrary characteristic?

Comment: Kazhdan-Lusztig and Lusztig type conjectures are equivalent to a certain graded ring being positively graded and semi-simple in degree zero. Of course this is step 0 towards being Koszul!

Comment: Perhaps the intro of "Modular Koszul duality" http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.3760v1.pdf is helpful. In particular the remarks after Theorem 1.2.1

Comment: Thanks, Geordie! So I guess that means that (Koszul -->> KL polynomials) and that the converse is not necessarily true - but perhaps is expected to be true?

Comment: Basically yes. My understanding is that "positive grading with semi-simple degree 0" is the really hard part (i.e. the bridge the KL polynomials). I expect that in the examples one has once one knows Lusztig style conjectures then Koszulity should hold. (By the numerical criterion for example, as Ben mentions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Geordie already started the shameless self-promotion:  I believe you can apply the results of section 1 of [Canonical bases and higher representation theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0051) to show that this will happen whenever the graded version of this $q$-Schur algebra (which you may need to believe [a conjecture of Riche and Williamson](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08296) to define) is Morita equivalent to a positively graded algebra.  So asking for Koszulity is, as Geordie points out, actually overkill.

That said,  I think Koszulity will likely follow in this case: an argument like in [Notes on parameters of quiver Hecke algebras](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1776.pdf) by Kashiwara should show that this positivity will only happen if the base change from characteristic 0 to characteristic $p$ sends simples to simples, in which case the numerical criterion shows that Koszulity is preserved.

Comment: Sorry Ben, when you say "the graded version of this $q$-Schur algebra (which you may need to believe a conjecture of Riche and Williamson to define)" what do you mean?  Didn't you and Catharina construct this over any field?

Comment: @ChrisBowman I think that only works in type A.  I assume you want an arbitrary reductive algebraic group.